# Bootstrap Sidebar collapsing when it shouldn't and not collapsing when it should

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Have a Sidebar in a MVC project, created from DB and injected as HTML on view.

On the whole, it works well apart from two annoying traits.

1. If  submenu items are opened they don't collapse if another one is opened
2. If a submenu item is clicked it does collapse when it should stay open

This needs to be the other way round

Probably an easy CSS issue, but after going through it nothing jumps out.

The generated HTML is

```
div class="nav-side-menu">
    <div class="brand">Band Name</div>
    <i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x toggle-btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menu-content"></i>
    <div class="menu-list">
        <ul id="menu-content" class="menu-content collapse out">
            <li data-toggle="collapse" class="collapsed active"><a href="#1"><i class="fa fa-gift fa-lg"></i>Overview<span class="arrow"></span></a></li>
            <li data-toggle="collapse" class="collapsed active"><a href="#2"><i class="fa fa-gift fa-lg"></i>Terms of Use (Licence)<span class="arrow"></span></a></li>
            <li data-toggle="collapse" class="collapsed active"><a href="#3"><i class="fa fa-gift fa-lg"></i>System Requirements<span class="arrow"></span></a></li>
            <li data-toggle="collapse" class="collapsed active"><a href="#4"><i class="fa fa-gift fa-lg"></i>Installation<span class="arrow"></span></a></li>
            <li data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#5" class="collapsed active">
                <a><i class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"></i>Message Centre  <span class="caret" ></span></a>
                <ul class="sub-menu collapse" id="5">
                    <li><a href="#6">News</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#7">Communications</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#8" class="collapsed active">
                <a><i class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"></i>Website  <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="sub-menu collapse" id="8">
                    <li><a href="#9">Login</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the CSS is

```
<style>
    .nav-side-menu {
        overflow: auto;
        font-family: verdana;
        font-size: 12px;
        font-weight: 200;
        background-color: #2e353d;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0px;
        width: 300px;
        height: 100%;
        color: #e1ffff;
    }

        .nav-side-menu .brand {
            background-color: #23282e;
            line-height: 50px;
            display: block;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 14px;
        }

        .nav-side-menu .toggle-btn {
            display: none;
        }

        .nav-side-menu ul,
        .nav-side-menu li {
            list-style: none;
            padding: 0px;
            margin: 0px;
            line-height: 35px;
            cursor: pointer;

        }

            .nav-side-menu ul :not(collapsed) .arrow:before,
            .nav-side-menu li :not(collapsed) .arrow:before {
                font-family: FontAwesome;
                content: "\f078";
                display: inline-block;
                padding-left: 10px;
                padding-right: 10px;
                vertical-align: middle;
                float: right;
            }

            .nav-side-menu ul .active,
            .nav-side-menu li .active {
                border-left: 3px solid #d19b3d;
                background-color: #4f5b69;
            }

            .nav-side-menu ul .sub-menu li.active,
            .nav-side-menu li .sub-menu li.active {
                color: #d19b3d;
            }

                .nav-side-menu ul .sub-menu li.active a,
                .nav-side-menu li .sub-menu li.active a {
                    color: #d19b3d;
                }

            .nav-side-menu ul .sub-menu li,
            .nav-side-menu li .sub-menu li {
                background-color: #181c20;
                border: none;
                line-height: 28px;
                border-bottom: 1px solid #23282e;
                margin-left: 0px;
            }

                .nav-side-menu ul .sub-menu li:hover,
                .nav-side-menu li .sub-menu li:hover {
                    background-color: #020203;
                }

                .nav-side-menu ul .sub-menu li:before,
                .nav-side-menu li .sub-menu li:before {
                    font-family: FontAwesome;
                    content: "\f105";
                    display: inline-block;
                    padding-left: 10px;
                    padding-right: 10px;
                    vertical-align: middle;
                }

        .nav-side-menu li {
            padding-left: 0px;
            border-left: 3px solid #2e353d;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #23282e;
        }

            .nav-side-menu li a {
                text-decoration: none;
                color: #e1ffff;
            }

                .nav-side-menu li a i {
                    padding-left: 10px;
                    width: 20px;
                    padding-right: 20px;
                }

            .nav-side-menu li:hover {
                border-left: 3px solid #d19b3d;
                background-color: #4f5b69;
                -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
                -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
                -o-transition: all 1s ease;
                -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
                transition: all 1s ease;
            }

    @media (max-width: 767px) {
        .nav-side-menu {
            position: relative;
            width: 100%;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
        }

            .nav-side-menu .toggle-btn {
                display: block;
                cursor: pointer;
                position: absolute;
                right: 10px;
                top: 10px;
                z-index: 10 !important;
                padding: 3px;
                background-color: #ffffff;
                color: #000;
                width: 40px;
                text-align: center;
            }

        .brand {
            text-align: left !important;
            font-size: 22px;
            padding-left: 20px;
            line-height: 50px !important;
        }
    }

    @media (min-width: 767px) {
        .nav-side-menu .menu-list .menu-content {
            display: block;
        }

        #main {
            width: calc(100% - 300px);
            float: right;
        }
    }

    body {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first issue, you can simply wrap the accordion portion of the menu with an id:

```
<div class="accordion-group">
```

Then add this JS code to fix your accordion problem:

```
/* ensure any open panels are closed before showing selected */
$('.accordion-group').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
  $('.accordion-group .in').collapse('hide');
});
```

For the second issue, you just need to move the `data-toggle="collapse"` and `data-target="#5"` to the `a` element of the sub-menu so that the anchor is the only thing that toggles the collapse (not the entire list item which includes all of its content).

```
<li class="collapsed active">
  <a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#5"><i></i>Message Centre  <span class="caret" ></span></a>
 ...
</li>
```

Demo: **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wa0nLaza/3/)**

Comment: Thank you for your time in producing that :-) I placed the accordion group divs between the <li> tags to prevent the nesting errors, and now that works perfectly. This other issue is that if a main menu item is opened, displaying the sub menu items and a user clicks on a sub menu item I don't want the main menu to collapse as it shows them where they have currently navigated from

Comment: Just to confirm. If the main menu item is clicked it should do what it is doing, open if collapsed and collapse if open, and close any other open ones. However if a sub menu item is clicked (e.g. Communications) then it should not close the parent

Comment: @gchq See the edited post above for a solution.  [**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/wa0nLaza/3/)

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much :-)