# Nested Bootstrap Sidebar item throwing the toys out

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

With thanks to [trevorp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45381376/bootstrap-sidebar-collapsing-when-it-shouldnt-and-not-collapsing-when-it-should) the basic side nav bar works perfectly. Then I needed to nest some menu items. This seems logical to me

```
<li class="collapsed active">
                <div class="accordion-group">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#20"><i class="dropdown-toggle"></i>Accounting  <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="sub-menu collapse" id="20">
                        <li class="collapsed active">
                            <div class="accordion-group">
                                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#21"><i class="dropdown-toggle"></i>Income  <span class="caret"></span></a>
                                <ul class="sub-menu collapse" id="21">
                                    <li><a href="#49">Customers</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#22">Purchases</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#23">General Ledger</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#24">Banks</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#25">Invoicing</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#26">Financials</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#27">Utilities</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#28">Reports</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
```

But it produced this result

[image: Menu Item]

That just closes when clicked, instead of opening the li item... It's probably something very basic, but the art of staring at it hasn't produced any results yet :-)

I suspect clicking on the sub menu item is closing the parent, but no idea how to overcome that. No idea why the formatting is totally different either!

Thank you

======================= UPDATE =======================

If the second accordion-group div is removed it takes care for the blank menu item, and disabling the script

```
<script>

/* ensure any open panels are closed before showing selected */
$('.accordion-group').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
    $('.accordion-group .in').collapse('hide');
});
```

that closes the main menu items when another is opened now gives this result..

[image: Menu item - top selected]

[image: Menu item - sub menu item selected]

That now leaves two questions

1. How can I select a sub menu item without closing the accordion group?
2. How can I format the sub menu items in the same colour as the others (white not orange)?

Comment: Try changing your ids to not start with numbers. Example: `id=
"item-21"`

Comment: brenjt - not sure how that would help, the entire thing is built from code-behind using a back-end DB from the controller, then rendered on the view as html. The basic menu (without nested items) works fine. Did try with a sandboxed version, but still the same issue

Comment: What is the parent ul of `<li class="collapsed active">`?
Are you loading the `.js` files that bootstrap requires?

Comment: fauverism - the parent is             <ul id="menu-content" class="menu-content collapse out">. Yes all js files loaded and everything works apart from the nested menu item

Comment: It's invalid to start an ID with a number. Some browsers might not apply any styles associated with that ID. It probably won't fix your issue, but you should change them regardless

Comment: sean - we can prefix every number with something like menu_ whilst it's returning the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally managed to find a way to solve question one

If there is a less verbose method I'd love to hear :-)

Add an onlick method to the sub-menu item

```
<li class="collapsed active">
                                    <a onclick="holdCollapse();" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Menu_21" class="dropdown-toggle  collapsed"><i class="fa fa-gift fa-lg"></i>Income  </a>
                                    <ul class="sub-menu collapse" id="Menu_21">
                                        <li><a href="#Menu_49">Customers</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
```

and add a hidden field

```
 <input type="hidden" value="0" id="HiddenField" />
```

add this script

```
<script>
function holdCollapse(e) {
    $('#HiddenField').val('1');
}
```

and edit the original script

```
<script>
/* ensure any open panels are closed before showing selected */
$('.accordion-group').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
    var isSubMenu = $('#HiddenField').val();
    if (isSubMenu == '0') {
        $('.accordion-group .in').collapse('hide');
    }
    $('#HiddenField').val('0');

       });
```